# remove duplicates data from complex json file in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a complex json file it included nested dics in it. 
it looks like this

```
{
    "objectivelist": [{
        "measureid": "1122",
        "gradeID": "4222332",
        "graduationdate": "May",
        "system": {
            "platform": "MAC",
            "TeacherName": "Mike",
            "manager": "Jim",
            "studentinfomation": {
                "ZIP": "94122",
                "city": "SF"
            }
        },
        "measureid": "1122",
        "gradeID": "4222332",
        "graduationdate": "May",
        "system": {
            "platform": "MAC",
            "TeacherName": "joshe",
            "manager": "steven"
        },
        "studentinfomation": {
            "ZIP": "94122",
            "city": "SF"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here the grade ID and Measured ID are the same, so the result should only need to show one times, and my result should be like this:

```
{"measureid":"1122","gradeID"4222332","graduationdate":"May"}
```

I do not need the managername, teachername etc.

not sure how to do this.  I try to use comprehensation but do not know who to use it in nest dictionary.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Your json has lots of bad syntax. Can you please fix the JSON?

Comment: At least tree bugs in the JSON according to https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: sorry guys, does this works now?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how huge the json file is you may need better solution. We will hash fields which are of interest to us and build the unique json iteratively.

```
check_set = set()
output = []
interesting_fields = ['measureid', 'gradeID', 'graduationdate']
for dat in X['objectivelist']:
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(dat['measureid'].encode('utf-8'))
    m.update(dat['gradeID'].encode('utf-8'))
    m.update(dat['graduationdate'].encode('utf-8'))
    digest = m.hexdigest()

    if digest not in check_set:
        output.append({key: dat[key] for key in ['measureid', 'gradeID', 'graduationdate']})
        check_set.add(digest)
```

And you can find your output in `output`.